# Browser doesn't show index page made by index.js and index.jade on Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to show index page by index.js and index.jade on Node.js, however browser returns the page only show index.html as attached picture. 
I set the index.js as routes as following, thus I think the root path should return index page.

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', sessionCheck, routes);
```

The following is my present code. Could you tell me what is the problem?

```
###app.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var login = require('./routes/login');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000 // 30min.
  }
}));

var sessionCheck = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
};

app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});    
module.exports = app;


###routes/index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;


###views/index.jade
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

[image: When I access the localhost]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.
Becuase I set the root directory '/public', I could not access index.js.Thank you for you kindeness.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```